# Using 'geoWithin' with something like 'near'

Tags: mongodb, meteor, geospatial

I'm trying to implement a search feature that searches for places in a location and also within a distance outside this.

This is what i have so far: (using Meteor)

```
Places.find({
    location: {
        $geoWithin: {
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Polygon',
                coordinates: [[[-3.2714903,51.4671222], ... ]]
            }
        }
    }
}).fetch();
```

This finds all places that are within this polygon correctly...but I also want to ba able to find places that are 3 miles outside this too (hoping this makes sense)

I want to be able to implement something like the $maxDistance option on $near

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction, Thanks

Comment: Try the query and then ask "What is the problem"

Answer (score 0):

Different version of MongoDB support different geo indexes and query options. Meteor used to only support older MongoDB versions (before 1.0.4). I had to try differnt approaches and this is what worked for me since Meteor 0.9:

```
var query = {
        loc: {
            $nearSphere: {
                $geometry: user.watchLocation,
                $maxDistance: 1000 //1 km
            }
        }
    };
```

With a 2dsphere index:

```
Places._ensureIndex({
    loc: "2dsphere"
});
```

And having the `place.loc` attribute as well as the `user.watchlocation` stored in the following format:

```
place.loc = {
     type: "Point",
     coordinates: [pos.lng, pos.lat]
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Florian! Tried this first ... but by having $nearSphere you are only getting results 1km from the centre of the location (rather than 1km from the locations perimeter)?

Comment: You are right, I overlooked the polygon perimeter in your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called "buffering". Add a buffer to the polygon, then do a `$geoWithin` your new buffered polygon.

If that 3-mile range is static, I'd suggest saving it as a separate `searchRange` field & indexing that. OR, offload this to the client :-)

If you want to differentiate between POIs within the original shape & those within the buffer, do an additional query on the returned results against the original shape. Since the list should be greatly reduced, no need for an index here.

Here's a simple tool to get you started: https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-buffer